# Upgrade ng-boilerplate to use angular ui bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, bower, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.3 with a project using ng-boilerplate. I want to use Bootstrap 3 so I've changed the bower file to use the branch for version 3, but now grunt fails when running the karma tests. I've isolated the problem to module dependencies on ui.bootstrap but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had to build the angular-ui-bootstrap package with grunt and change build.config.js vendor_files to use `vendor/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.min.js`

Comment: were you building the bootstrap3_bis2 branch or master? I wish there was a statement from angular bootstrap about their bs3 compatiblity, I'm not sure if I should try doing this or wait...

Comment: ... actually FYI to anyone who sees this, it looks like https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/742 tracks progress of their Bootstrap 3 efforts.

Comment: bootstrap3_bis2 branch and thanks for the useful link

Comment: Following these leads, I just forked ng-boilerplate and got it going with bootstrap 3.  [Here it is](https://github.com/abeluga/ng-boilerplate/tree/v0.3.1-release).  

Note: if you're going to use Angular UI, then you need to build angular-ui-bootstrap by going into vendor/angular-ui-bootstrap and running grunt (after 'npm install').  Then uncomment the line in following in `build.config.coffee`, and test it out by including `"ui-bootstrap"` in the dependencies at the top of `about.coffee`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to fork it for now and change the dependency on ui.bootstrap to use their BS3 branch found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3_bis2

Comment: I figured out that when I updated bower.json, I had to change the devDependencies from "angular-bootstrap": "~0.3.0" to "angular-ui-bootstrap": "#bootstrap3_bis2".

Comment: @gwhn, that branch no longer exists :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're relatively new to ng-boilerplate and want to get jump started with angular support for boostrap3 this fork might be helpful.

https://github.com/MorrisLLC/ng-boilerplate

It uses the lastest versions of the boilerplate vendor libraries and most recent versions of the grunt tasks.

See the Quick Start for modified instructions on building angular-bootstrap. You have to build it because the current angular bootstrap branch does not include the tpls files (templates).

Comment: My opinion today would be to consider Yeoman for scaffolding a new Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and already had written a lot in bootstrap 2.3.2. Instead of starting all over with someone else's git repo, you could just update several files:

- build.config.js add in the vendor/bootstrap/js/.js where the file is the javascript that you are planning to use.
- less/main.less which imports the bootstrap less. You could use specific less files from bootstrap or do an import of everything with:

  ```
  @import '../../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
  ```